# Шаблон не редактируется, параметры не сохраняются в joomla

Tags: шаблоны, joomla

Всем привет, суть проблемы в том, что я не могу нормально отредактировать шаблон в joomla, страница index.php не сохраняется и .css файлы не редактируются.
Так же мне надо вставить карту от яндекс в статью а сделать я этого не могу, так как точно не помню как именно можно разрешить вставку scripta.
Пытался кое что поменять в настройках, при этом вылазит сообщение что параметры не сохраняются в configuration.php, я так понял там нужно установить права, но как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

По поводу прав: можно посмотреть в **справке->информация о системе**, там выберете **права и папки**: появится список с правами на папки **cms joomla**.
Конечно выскажу очевидное: разрабатывайте сайт на локалке, а потом заливайте на сервер, например при помощи **total commander**, ставя необходимые права на папки.
Вставку скрипта можно выполнить следующим образом: **Материалы->Менеджер материалов->Параметры** (в низу и из списка "**Параметры фильтрации**" надо выбрать Registered, а в параметре "**Тип фильтрации**" Чёрный список, все сохранить. Также есть куча сторонних модулей для вставки стороннего скрипта (ссори за тавтологию), например **Jumi,Joomla Mod PHP**.
А так в принципе стандартных средств хватает для этих целей, надо лишь знать нужные настройки (коих много).